# Bootstrap modal with a YouTube video iframe console error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'postMessage"

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube, console, bootstrap-modal

I have a bootstrap modal that lazy loads an iframe YouTube video via some JavaScript to help with page speed. Everything works fine, but I get a console error in Chrome related to some JS code that pauses and starts the video if the modal is closed and/or reopened. The error itself shows up when you click the "Watch Video" button which opens the modal.

Uncaught *TypeError: Cannot read property 'postMessage' of undefined* ...

How do I prevent the console error?

This code is causing the error:

```
    $('#videoModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (){$('.ytv').contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"playVideo","args":""}', '*')});

    $('#videoModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (){$('.ytv').contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"pauseVideo","args":""}', '*')});
```

Javascript

```
// Video Modal
    var div = document.getElementById("appVideoContainer");
    var span = div.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].contentWindow;

    $('#videoModalBtn').on("click", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('#videoModal').modal('show');
    });

    $('#videoModalCloseBtn').on("click", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('#videoModal').modal('hide');
    });


    //Lazy loading YouTube embed for faster page load
    var video_wrapper = $('.youtube-video-place');

    //  Check to see if youtube wrapper exists
    if (video_wrapper.length) {
      // If user clicks on the video wrapper load the video.
      $('.youtube-video-place').on('click', function() {

        // Dynamically inject the iframe on demand of the user. Pull the youtube url and ID from the data attribute on the wrapper element.
        $('#' + this.id).html('<iframe id="appVideo" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen allowscriptaccess="always" class="embed-responsive-item ytv" src="' + $(this).data("yt-url") + '"></iframe>');
      });
    }


    //Pause + Play YT video if Modal is closed or opened
    $('#videoModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
      $('.ytv')[0].contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"playVideo","args":""}', '*')
    });

    $('#videoModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
      $('.ytv')[0].contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"pauseVideo","args":""}', '*')
    });
```

HTML

```
 <!-- Video Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade video-modal" id="videoModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="videoModalLabel">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" id="videoModalCloseBtn"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div id="appVideoContainer" class="youtube-video-place embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 " data-yt-url="https://www.youtube.com/embed/XXZFco-1zpo?enablejsapi=1&rel=0&amp;showinfo=0&autoplay=1"><img src="https://echristo.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/service-1.jpg" async>
              <span></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: One solution is to change the iframe's URL on modal shown instead of before its created. 

`$(".ytv").attr("src", videoSrc+"?autoplay=1")` and just set a variable as videoSrc


`var videoSrc;

$('.youtube-video-place').on('click', function() {
videoSrc = $(this).data("yt-url")`

Comment: @imvain2 Thanks for the reply. That does seem to stop the console error, but it also seems to make the modal hidden not pause the video so that if the user closes and then re-opens the modal the video starts playing from where you left.